# Why isn't my component object getting updated itself when anything in my globally shared service updates? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, reference, angular-services, angular-components

I have this service:

```
    export class RecipeService{
    
        selectedRecipe: Recipe = 'xyz';
    }
```

I have this component using this service:

```js
    export class RecipesComponent implements OnInit {
    
      selectedRecipe: Recipe;
    
      constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.selectedRecipe = this.recipeService.selectedRecipe;
      }
    
    }
```

The service is defined in `app.module.ts` for injection, which means all components get the same instance.

My question is, whenever I update the `selectedRecipe` variable in one of my components, it doesn't get updated back in other components although it is referenced and hence I expect a change immediately.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled and found out in one of the posts that its because of my object. The object (`Recipe`) in my service contains a primitive type, i.e `string`. If your object contains a primitive type, it isn't passed as a reference, hence a change in service object won't be reflected in component because they are now different.

Although I must clear that in case of array it worked perfectly fine even when my array contained objects which had primitive types. Changes were still reflected.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get updated because the new value is not "sent" to the already initiated angular components.

Instead you should use observables.

for example:

```
/* service */
private recipe = "xyz";
public recipeSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(this.recipe);

// when changing the recipe
recipeSubject.next(this.recipe);

/* component */
this.service.recipeSubject.subscribe(res => this.recipe = res);
```

Comment: Yes I made it work through observable, but can you tell why we need to "sent" something? When its already referenced type, why isn't the object in component gets updated itself?

Comment: basically you send something when you want to notify your subscribers that the value has changed. when you read the value from a service, you only read it once.

Comment: so the connection is not a reference type, right? Old value means its pointing to its own address which needs to be updated through subscription evreytime.

Comment: I believe it works like that :) Did the answer help you?